# USB drive (Format disk + The volume does not contain a recognized file system)

Tags: usb, partition

Hello all i have a problem with usb drive.
I have tried with several programs but no one cant find my data on the USB.
It says cant find any partition on the usb.

The usb is RAW format and i cant use chkdsk in Command prompt.

I have tried with DISKPART and when i type select partition 1 it says there is no partitions.

Is there any chance to save my data?

Comment: Please post this question in superuser. Stack overflow is for programming related queries.